# Using jQuery selectors on object arrays that are NOT part of the DOM

Tags: jquery, css, arrays

I'm looking for ways to quickly filter an array of javascript objects. Ideally I'd like to use jQuery's CSS selectors, but there seems to be no way to get that to work. I feel like I'm missing something, because I haven't found any other people wondering the same thing. I seems so straight-forward that I can't imagine nobody has built a plug-in for this. :)

My array of objects may look like this:

```
var myArray = [{
  "description": "Foo?",
  "name": "foo"
}, {
  "description": "Bar!",
  "name": "bar"
}]
```

I'd like to find all elements with names 'bar' like this:
`$(myArray).find("[name='bar']")`

Comment: You could just use [filter](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) or [native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Underscore `find` methods would be great here. ) But yes, using either `$.grep` or `Array.filter` won't make the OP write a lot of boilerplate code - it still will be quite compact.

Answer (score 0):

If you've just got a javascript object to filter, just use the native filter method:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_filter.htm